# External component is taking full view [ReactJS]

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to import an external tag on my page so that it'll be visible in the dropdown area. But this external view is taking a full page. When I inspect this in console, I'm finding it above all `divs` but I'm placing it in the dropdown menu.

```
<Popover content={RequestFeatureModal} placement={'bottom'}>
    Request a feature
</Popover>
const RequestFeatureModal = (
    <Menu style={{ width: '100px' }}>
        <UpvotyWidget
          id="upvoty-display"
          style={{ maxHeight: '100px', maxWidth: '100px' }}
          baseUrl={'sample.upvoty.com/b/feature-requests'}
          boardHash={this.state.ssoToken}
        />
    </Menu>
);
```

Am I doing something wrong? What is the way to import external sources in our project at specific position?

Comment: The component is probably using postion:fixed.

Comment: That is not the case @Keith.

Comment: Sorry, really not enough info here.  Are you able to knock up a JSBIN or Snippet showing the problem.